# Updating on the fly RequireJS Configuration

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Do any ways to update *(not replace)* requireJS configuration on the fly?

For example we have such configuration:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'knockout': 'knockout/knockout-3.0.0',
        'ko-mapping': 'knockout/knockout.mapping-2.4.0',
    }
});
```

And want to add to it additional path on the fly...

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'knockout': 'knockout/knockout-3.0.0',
        'ko-mapping': 'knockout/knockout.mapping-2.4.0',
    }
});

//some code

//add to require config path 'mymodule':'module'

//some code
```

Comment: Strange feature to expect from RequireJs. Could you, please, describe specific use case for it? There should be another way to resolve it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. During implementation of current tasks I found another solution than changing RequireJS config on the fly. But this question is still interesting for me. So I'll be thankful if somebody help me to find an answer on it.